# How to configure dynamic environment variables for JS that will run in browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web, config

I have a requirement where **system environment variables** that we can get at **server side** (using `process.env.BLABLA` in **Node.js**) need also be injected in the pre-built JS file that will be served to the browser. The UI is made using Angular.

I have thought of three ways as of now in my mind :-

1. an API call to **/api/config** to get these **environment variables** and using them.
2. Let's say we have certain placeholder variable names in our JS files which will finally get bundled and served to browser. Before serving the bundled js file say , `bundle.js`, we replace those placeholders with the **environment variables**. The only thing is that `bundle.js` is quite huge (can't split it yet) and reading and writing might delay server start. Also don't know if this should be advocated.
3. We can dynamically generate another file, say, `config.js` (at server startup) with the dynamic **environment variables** and a logic to store them in **sessionStorage** when loaded in browser. This file will be loaded via separate `script` tag in the `index.html` before `bundle.js` and then in `bundle.js` there would be logic to derive the **environment variables** using `sessionStorage`. The only thing here is that a person can see these variables using the dev tools. As of now, I don't think that's a concern. Also if the user resets `sessionStorage` to any other values, it shouldn't matter as the values would already be set and used at load time and cleared at the `unload` event.

What are some good ways to go about this ? The first one is quite simple but I want to prevent a request after `bundle.js` execution.

Comment: Follow this guide, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/ This is awesome. You will get an idea. Although the link talks about React app but same can be applied to anything.

Comment: @ManishJangir Thanks for the link :). Kinda looks like the 3rd way I discussed here.

Comment: Yes I've used it so many times in React apps and it works like a charm. Very useful to get build machine's env variables at react app build time.

Comment: I'd probably use a hybrid of option 3) and just have config.js be a common script that every page loads and gets the config from.  Then, every page always has the config.  I don't see why you need to store it in session storage because then that exposes problems where some other page goes to load, but the config isn't in session storage yet.  And, fetching it as a script file, rather than an API call allows the browser to prefetch and cache more efficiently.

Comment: ALL client-side anything can be seen be dev tools - that's how browsers work - there is no private client-side anything in browsers.  If you don't want it seen, it has to only be on the server and can never be on the client so that has to be factored into what is client-side and what is kept server-side.

Comment: @jfriend00 Would exposing them using `window` be better than `session/localStorage` ?

Comment: "Better" in what way?  It would work fine exposing them via a single object that is available off `window` or even better to use ES6 modules and expose them in the exports of a config module.